# Index with both authors and subjects using natbib and makeidx

Tags: bibtex, natbib, indexing, imakeidx, makeidx

I am writing a book and trying to create an index that includes both authors (gathered from `natbib` references and the `\citeindextrue` command) and subjects (generated with the `makeidx` package and the `\index` command).

I am running into two issues.

First, I'd like to have first *and* last names of authors in the index. But I only figure out how to get the last names in the index. I can't figure out how to modify the following `bibtex` hack to include first names.

```
 \renewcommand\NAT@index{\@bsphack\begingroup \def~ 
 {\string~}\@wrindex{\NAT@myidxtxt}} 
\newcommand\NAT@myidxtxt{\NAT@name} 
 \makeatother
```

Second, once compiled, the author index created by `\citeindextrue` and the subject index created by the `\index{}` commands are alphabetized separately. Ideally, I'd like them merged into one index. Is this possible?

My book is setup something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\makeindex              
\citeindextrue
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\NAT@index{\@bsphack\begingroup
  \def~{\string~}\@wrindex{\NAT@myidxtxt}}
\newcommand\NAT@myidxtxt{\NAT@name}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Here is some indexed text \index{example} with some citations \citet{smith1996}.
\bibliography{references}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't get the first names, there are not stored in a accessible way in the bbl. Is a switch to biblatex/biber an option? The wrong sorting is due to additional braces around the name, you could try `\expandafter\@wrindex\NAT@name` instead of `\@wrindex{\NAT@myidxtxt}`.

Comment: Thanks, that resolved the sorting issue. Switching to biblatex/biber should be fine. Would I then use a similar hack to call the first names as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment by Ulrike Fischer notes that changing

```
\@wrindex{\NAT@myidxtxt}
```

to

```
\expandafter\@wrindex\NAT@name
```

solves the issue with sorting. Adding first names would require a switch to Biblatex or Biber.